# How to pass a list of files as a parameter in Python?

Tags: python, list, parameters, pyenchant

I'm working with the pyenchant spelling corrector and I'm trying to pass multiple files as a parameter in order to create a personal dictionary.
I have 82 additional text files stored in a folder and I would like to pass them to the function without typing every single file name. Is that possible with Python?
I've already tried creating a list of all the text files and then passing the list, but that didn't work.
Here is my code:

```
import enchant
import os

allfiles = os.listdir("dicts")   

dictpwl = enchant.DictWithPWL("de_DE", allfiles)
```

This yields the following error:

> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute '_request_dict_data'

Any suggestions on how to pass my text files in a different way?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: the documentation sucks!! seems that you have to create an object. Otherwise, drop the argument and try to call `for x in allfiles: dictpwl.add(x)`

Comment: This seems to work, thank you